# Track image upload progress in graphql mutation

Tags: reactjs, angular, graphql, apollo-client, mutation-observers

I am running a graphql mutation to upload an image to the server. And operation is done successfully. My only question is that how do i track the progress of image upload on frontend? What percentage of the image size is uploaded? I want to show it in the progressbar in the frontend.
Below is my graphql mutation

```
const { mutate: addProfilePicture } = useAddProfilePictureMutation<Error>(
graphqlRequestClient(graphqlEndpoint),
{
  onSuccess: (
    _data: AddProfilePictureMutation,
    _variables: AddProfilePictureMutationVariables,
    _context: unknown
  ) => {
    console.log(_data)
  },
}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Angular front-end, you could use [HTTP - Track and show request progress](https://angular.io/guide/http-track-show-request-progress).